# Adding x64 platform configuration to VC++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, 64-bit, wizard

I'm using a `wizard` to set up a new `VC++` project in `VS2013`. I wish to add `platform`  `configurations` for both `WIN32` and `x64` to the project, using `default.js`, however, looking at the documentation for the project configurations, it seems `AddProject` is the only way I can do this, but for some reason, it is not for VC++ : 
[MSDN AddPlatform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.addplatform%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So, is there any other way to add the `x64` `platform` `configuration`?

Could it be possible to extract the x64 configuration out from an existing project, include it with the Wizard project, and copy that configuration instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add a line saying

```
proj.ConfigurationManager.AddPlatform("x64","Win32",true);
```

...in the `default.js` file.

That'll add the x64 configuration to the project.

Comment: This could be very useful to me. Could you please share more detail on `default.js` ?